# Can't add a package source to the NuGet Package Manager

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

I want to add a new package source to the NuGet Package Manager. By choosing Tools->NuGet Package Manager->Package Manager Settings I've arrived in the "Options" window. Then I've chosen Package Sources from NuGet Package Manager. The problem is that the "Plus" button is disabled.[image]

So how can I add a new source?

Comment: which VS and which NuGet Extension version? Also try to edit the "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.Config" with an editor and add the entry there

Answer (score 1):

[Known issue](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/2617) in NuGet extension in VS. Workaround as mentioned in the comment is to manually add a source in the nuget.config located at: %appdata%\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.Config. This fix will be available in 3.4.5 version of the NuGet extension (due later this month - June 2016)